# For eclipse which -vm is preferable?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jvm

I am using eclipse 3.6 
while using Virtual Machine, which one is better option.
**Option1:**

```
   -vm
    C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/javaw.exe
```

**Option2:**

```
   -vm
    C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/javaw.exe
```

it will help to put exact Virtual Machine for the Java/J2ee development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse it is always better to use the JDK.

Some Eclipse plugin require the JDK and not the JRE to work. There also other extra libs you get with the JDK that are not in the JRE

Answer (score 2):

For running an application you can use either one, they are the exact same.

The only difference is that the JDK package contains other useful executables such as javac, which aren't needed in the JRE, which is supposed to be as lightweight as possible from a size consideration. The idea behind this is that in the bad old days of 56K, a 70MB JDK was a huge hassle to download to simply run a program, hence the existence of the far smaller JRE package.

Comment: Small download sizes for the JRE are *still* relevant, especially if you auto-update or auto-deploy it.

Comment: Very true =) But it's not like the days when I had to factor in the cost of the phone bill to download the JDK in startup costs ;)

Comment: luckily not where I live and not in *most* parts of the world. I wouldn't bet that that is true *everywhere*, however.

Comment: In fact for Eclipse specifically, the JDK should be used. Eclipse even warns you if you don't use it.